# Convert xlsx to JSON format?

Tags: php, json, excel

Which library would you suggest for converting a `xlsx` file into `JSON` with `PHP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHPExcel (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to read and parse the file in to an array of your preferred structure, then just json_encode that array and output with json headers.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. :) Seems to be the only one with that many features anyways.

Comment: please don't reward bad questions (including questions that are *explicitely off-topic*) with answers.

Comment: @Franz yes, his question is not code based, but it is quite legit and relevant to quite a few beginners. If questions like this get answered and indexed, then maybe ppl can actually stumble upon the answer via google and not ask same open question again and again (btw it is not off-topic as the topic is defined by OP, it is simply not the kind of question that SO rules encourage because it is an open question and can lead to a useless debate)